# Submanifolds of Torus

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, tangent-spaces

I want to describe submanifolds of $T^4:=\mathbb{R}^4/\mathbb{Z}^4$ which are of the type symplectic or lagrangian or isotropic or coisotropic (using the standard symplectic structure $dx_1 \wedge d y_1+dx_2 \wedge d y_2$.

My problem is, that, except guessing, I don't see a method of finding these.

For the standard euclidean product, in 2 or 3 dimensions I can imagine how the tangent space of a point looks like and how its orthogonal complement must look like (using the "graphical interpretation" of orthogonal). But I don't know how to visualise a symplectic product. Does somebody have some hints on that or general hints how to solve this?

Comment: Aren't all submanifolds of $T^4$ just lower dimensional tori? So any one, two or three linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with integer coordinates define a submanifold and all submanifolds can be described like that. Afterwards you can check which of these are of the types you want.

Comment: @quarague: No, not necessarily. Every closed surface embeds in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and hence in any four-manifold (use a coordinate chart).

Comment: I suggest you first work this out in the case of $R^4$.

Comment: Ok, I know that each 1-dim. submanifold is isotropic and each hypersurface is coisotropic. So the image of the smooth curve $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow T^4, t \mapsto t \cdot (1 ,0,0,0)$ should be a 1-dim. submanifold and therefore isotropic, is that correct?

Comment: Also, is $S^4 / \mathbb{Z}^4$ a submanifold of $T^4$? Then this would be a hypersurfacce and therefore coisotropic.